# Flagging a job is fine but is it possible to flag a company page

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, stack-overflow-jobs

Feature Request:
Is there a way to flag a company page.  In the case that their might be errors on the company page?  It doesn't necessarily mean there is something very wrong about the company but to help in case we come across something that just doesn't look right.

Answer (score 1):

As I've said before, company pages are in a bit flux. They may be changed dramatically in the future, they may not, but it's something we're discussing. For now, while not the best solution, feel free to send us an email at careers@stackoverflow.com