# Privacy settings don't allow video so don't bother showing it?

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

Pampered chef wants you to work for them.  They include a video on their [company page](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/companies/pampered-chef).  However, this video doesn't work **because of its privacy settings, this video cannot be played here.**.

I'm not sure where these privacy settings are stored but it defeats the purpose of even having it.  There is no link to an external site or anything that would help you see this video.

Feature request, remove these if you cannot see them otherwise you get this:

[image]

Comment: Aside: I love that they list one of their benefits as "great location near White Castle". THAT'S the kind of pampered chef I wanna be! Also, now I'm really hungry.

Answer (score 7):

I'll reach out to the customer get it fixed.

Comment: Hence for a need to flag company pages.  http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312723/flagging-a-job-is-fine-but-is-it-possible-to-flag-a-company-page